# Android Intent ACTION.SEND -- can't send text to Twitter or Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, twitter

I am having trouble when I try to pass a text string from within an EditText to either Facebook or Twitter via an intent. In fact, the only option which works currently is email.
The code I am using is below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textVariable.getText());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Title");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Text"));
```

I have tried it with and without the subject line. Any thoughts?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

To share the text on Facebook and Twitter the way you are using is not correct. You need to try out the other way of sharing.

Just refer [Link](http://vnstep.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/share-via-android/) it will guide you on how to share the text on facebook & twitter using intent.

Answer (score 1):

Look [Share bitmap with text on Twitter, Email & bitmap on Facebook in Android using Intent](http://connectcoders.blogspot.in/2012/12/share-image-with-text-on-twitter.html)

You can share image with text caption on twitter but on `facebook` you can not share text caption using `Intent`, for that you have to use `Facebook` SDK.

Comment: Thanks! The links provide individual ways for each of Facebook, Twitter etc, but is there a way of just having a share button which comes up with all of the options you can choose? At the moment all of the options show, but only Gmail actually carries the text through to the app.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick!

```
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.twitter.android",
                "com.twitter.applib.composer.TextFirstComposerActivity"));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        context.startActivity(intent);
               // Success!

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // official twitter code missing
    }
```